# Indluxdb Group By isnt working

Tags: group-by, influxdb

I have a problem with my influxdb. I try to put data in and group it by time. but its not working.

`SELECT mean(b) FROM foo WHERE time >= now() - 8h GROUP BY time(30s) fill(previous)`

no response

`SELECT count(b) FROM foo WHERE time >= now() - 8h 
name: foo`

`time                count
----                -----
1531372030476460080 7`

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE time >= now() - 8h`

`name: foo
time                a   b c
----                -   - -
1531405544000000000 1.4 1 3.6
1531405554000000000 1.4 1 3.6
1531406929000000000 1.4 1 3.6
1531406935000000000 1.4 1 3.6
1531406939000000000 1.4 1 3.6
1531406988000000000 1.4 1 3.6
1531406989000000000 1.4 1 3.6`

I have checked the datatypes of a,b,c and they are all float. As you can see count and mean is working but the group by feature want do. 
Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: Which one of the 3 query is not working?